# How do you make pyttsx3 actually wait after saving to file?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I am working on a project involving pyttsx3 TTS, since I prefer my TTS to happen offline and not hit any API limits. Thus, I chose pyttsx3, since it lets me save to file (in principle). However, it seems that

```
engine.init()
engine.save_to_file(text, file)
engine.runAndWait()
```

does not wait long enough to save to the requested file, should the string be too long.  If I add

```
time.sleep(10)
```

to the end, the file appears. In a project with a multitude of files being TTS'd sequentially, they all end up in the same folder, but that is another issue.

Am I interpreting this correctly? Whether or not I am, does anyone know a solution or better library to use?

I have tested this on two arch linux machines.

Thank you for your input.